# How to run a cron for specific time interval with 5 minutes interval

Tags: cron

Need to run a cron from 2 AM to 6 AM at 5 minutes interval.

```
*/5 02-06 * * *
```

is the command I am running. It runs cron as intended. But it do not stop at 6 AM and keeps on running.

I want it to stop by 6 AM.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll need two schedules:

[`*/5 2-5 * * *`](https://crontab.guru/#*/5_2-5_*_*_*)`/your/job`

and

[`0 6 * * *`](https://crontab.guru/#0_6_*_*_*)`/your/job`

Answer (score 0):

Your crontab entry will function as you described.  You'll have to **look for something else that is running the activity you are seeing**.  It's not the crontab entry in your example.

The details of how to verify the actual crontab entry is below in the **verification** section.

Use comas to specify the specific hours:

This will run the last interval at 6:55:

```
*/5 2,3,4,5,6 * * * command
```

This will run the last interval at 5:55:

```
*/5 2,3,4,5 * * * command
```

**This will do the same:**

Last interval at 6:55:

```
*/5 2-6 * * * command
```

Last interval at 5:55:

```
*/5 2-5 * * * command
```

### Verification:

You can verify the above by specifying an hour that is inclusive and using another test that doesn't include the current hour of the day.

The time of this test is **23:40**.  This crontab entry puts out an output:

```
* 021-023 * * * date >> /tmp/date.out
```

This crontab doesn't run the command:

```
* 021-022 * * * date >> /tmp/date.out
```

Using this command I can see the updates every minute when the hour is inclusive:

```
$ tail -f /tmp/date.out

Fri Feb  3 23:33:01 EST 2017
Fri Feb  3 23:34:01 EST 2017
Fri Feb  3 23:35:01 EST 2017
```

Comment: Use of comas will specify cron to run at 2,3,4,5,6 I think. I have just specified the time interval that means to start at 2 and stop at 6 at 5 minutes interval for these 4 hours.

Comment: The hours under the hour column will perform what is in the minutes column.  So the five minute cycle will happen in the hour of 2, 3, 4, all the way up and including 6.  Since 7 isn't and the other numbers are not specified.  The cron won't happen doing those hours.  Just every 5 minutes ruing the hours specified.

Comment: If you don't want it running at 6 you would have to eliminate the **6** from the mix.

Comment: James I don't want it to run after 6 till next day.

Comment: Look at my amended answer with explanation.  If you include 6 in the mix, it will continue to run until the hour of 6 is complete.  You won't see any more iterations starting at 7:00.  You have to exclude 6 if you don't want it to happen doing that hour.

Comment: Actually James, cron does not stop till I have to manually stop it after 6. It goes upto 10 or 11 or so on.

Comment: Use the commas.  If you put just **1** for the hour.  Nothing will happen at 2, 3, 4, up to 24.  If you put **1,2** then the action will only happen at 1 and 2.  Make a special test with the command being `date >>/tmp/date.out`.   Do it with minutes, and notice that the only action that will happen is what is specified in the minutes separated by commas.  If you see something happen, it may be the results of some other application that is running.  Test it with a very specific task, such as the **date** reference.

Comment: I tested the minutes column before posting my message.  I tested it with `date >>/tmp/date.out`.  Then I ran `tail -f /tmp/date.out` to tract when it runs and when it stops.

Comment: Notice that I have **2-5** for the hour.  If you're having a problem it might be the leading **0**.  Change the **02-06** to **2-6** for the hour... or better yet, use the commas, **2,3,4,5,6**.

Comment: @Diya00067 I just tested using the leading **0**.  That works also.   I'll add the details to my answer to make it easier to visualize.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto  end of story. search before asking or answering. the "how to" is there and it's almost a clone of the answer :D Diya read the guide and if you don't understand ask for more details :D

Comment: @PavlosTheodorou The howto is used in my answer.  If you look at the details of my answer, you will see that it works.  It includes test to verify it works.

Comment: Sorry to say but this method does not work for me.

Comment: @Diya00067 You're saying this line `* 021-023 * * * date >> /tmp/date.out` doesn't output the date for two hours and stop?